# (Javacard) Class Error Test of APDU Command 'Select File'

Tags: class, javacard, apdu

there

I don't understand why the Error 'Class is Not Supported' does not occur.

Firstly, my source code and APDU commands are as follows

< Source Code >

```
package SelectFileTest;
import javacard.framework.*;

public class SelectFileTest extends Applet{
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new SelectFileTest(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
    }   
    private SelectFileTest(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength){     
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu){
        byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        if (buf[1]==(byte)0xA4) {       
            if((buf[0]&0xff)!=0x00)                         // Class Check (Question)
                ISOException.throwIt((short)0xfff5);

            if(selectingApplet()) 
                {   }
            else
                ISOException.throwIt((short)0xffff);        // 6881
        }
        return ;
    }
}
```

< APDU Command >

```
[Card-1C] <== 00 A4 04 00 07 A0000000031234
[Card-1R] ==> 9000
[Card-2C] <== 00 A4 00 00 02 F801
[Card-2R] ==> FFFF                              // Expected
[Card-3C] <== 01 A4 00 00 02 F801
[Card-3R] ==> 6881                              // (Question) Expect the SW 'FFF5'
[Card-4C] <== 08 A4 00 00 02 F801
[Card-4R] ==> FFF5                              // Expected
```

By the command 3 and 4, the card must output the SW 'FFF5' because of the line 'Class Check'in source code. But, it outputs 6881(3R) (maybe by JCRE) at CLA=01~07.

I know that once the applet is selected, the JCRE forwards all subsequent APDUs commands to the selected applet. Therefore, I think the 3rd response(3R) is also 'FFF5' like 4R. I don't understand and couldn't find my mistakes in my code.

I hope your valuable comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the CLA byte the logical channel is indicated in the lower bits. You are selecting a logical channel which *the platform* then tries to send to the correct applet. It will however not find any open channel except the basic one (with ID = 0). So the platform will handle the error instead of the Applet. This happens *before* the Applet receives the APDU; the Applet will not be notified.

Note that this can also happen for the `INS: MANAGE CHANNEL`. I probably don't have to explain that SELECT by AID is also initially handled by the runtime environment.

More information about logical channels and how they *might* be utilized can be found in the ISO/IEC 7816-4.

Comment: Actually, I want that my applet handles all commands and error codes once it is selected. So, do you have the way for my applet to output FFF5?

Comment: @user2642459 Lower bits of CLA bytes are interpreted by the platform *before* sending the APDU to your applet. That is why your applet will with the correct logical channel only (the rest of CLA byte is all yours).

Answer (score 0):

Actually once I faced this problem because of class byte I set in my code... Because of my class byte my command is aborted and give me what i don't expect...

You need to decode the meaning of class byte before send it to card. ISO 7816 -3 and -4 will be helpful here to exact decode of your class byte...

Hope it helps...

Comment: (Same question above) Actually, I want that my applet handles all commands and error codes once it is selected. So, do you have the way for my applet to output FFF5?

Comment: when send command to java card, it handle by JCRE first, and  then it pass command to Process method.  here in your case JCRE returning this error, you will get your set SW1SW2 in return when JCRE will find command suitable to move it to Process Method.

Comment: 6881: Function not supported - Logical channel not supported/open, you can also check something here - https://community.oracle.com/thread/3576438 , it is related to same error you are getting.